# Python won't insert element at the start of the array

Tags: python

I have an 2d array and into every array that it contains, I want to insert value at the beggining.

I am using this:

```
def normalizeBox(self,boxes,x_,y_,addProbability):
    for box in boxes:
        box[0]*=x_
        box[1]*=y_
        box[2]*=x_
        box[3]*=y_
        if(addProbability == True):
            box = [float(1)] + box
```

But it does not insert anything. Why is this happening? All values are `float`.

Comment: `box = ...` just rebinds the `box` variable to a new object. To actually change the content of `boxes`, you'll need to mutate the object, e.g. with `box.insert()`.

Comment: I am using this code in another module and it works as it should. But yes, box.insert() fixed problem thanks

Comment: Isn't assigning to a slice like `box[:0] = [1.0]` the idiomatic way of inserting into a list?

Comment: @MikeSamuel If you're inserting multiple elements at once? Sure. Seems a little obtuse for inserting a single element when there's `insert()`, but that's probably a matter of opinion.

Comment: @glibdud, fair enough.